# Question mark in url pattern

Tags: django, django-urls

Django 1.11.2

I need an url pattern for two cases:

1. /blog/
2. /blog/.json/

So, in case of json, I'll respond with application/json content type.

This URL pattern seems to be acceptable:

```
url(r'^blog/?(?P<json>\.json)?/$', BlogFront.as_view()),
```

At least, it works. The problem is I can't understand it.

The last ? is to match 0 or 1 repetitions of the preceding RE. It's ok.
The ? in the middle is about capturing a symbolic group.

What about the first question mark? This is a mystery to me. Could you comment what does it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question mark just makes the preceeding `/` optional, making `/blog.json/` valid. According to your question this isn't what you want so probably worth removing it